# R: emmeans back-transformation when using a constant value in the response formula

Tags: r, regression, mixed-model, post-hoc, back-transformation

I am fitting a linear mixed model

```
LM.fit=lmer(sqrt(18-FAB)~Group*visit_num+Age+sexe+(1|num_sujet),data)

em<-emmeans(LM.fit,~Group,type="response")

Group response    SE  df lower.CL upper.CL
 G1       0.532 0.116 280    0.328    0.785
 G2       1.072 0.192 295    0.727    1.483
 G3       1.134 0.105 278    0.936    1.350

Results are averaged over the levels of: visit_num, sexe 
Degrees-of-freedom method: kenward-roger 
Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the sqrt scale 

pairs(regrid(em),adjust="bonferroni")

 contrast  estimate    SE  df t.ratio p.value
 G1- G2    -0.5741 0.223 277  -2.570  0.0321
 G1- G3    -0.5852 0.153 275  -3.837  0.0005
 G2- G3    -0.0111 0.211 275  -0.053  1.0000

Results are averaged over the levels of: visit_num, sexe 
Degrees-of-freedom method: inherited from kenward-roger when re-gridding 
P value adjustment: bonferroni method for 3 tests
```

When I look at the estimates it's very clear that something went wrong during the back-transformation.

**How Can I back transform using emmeans to have the estimate in the "FAB" scale and not in the "sqrt(18-FAB)" scale ?**

Comment: The transformation is too complex to be correctly auto-detected. If I had to guess, your back-transformed estimates are estimates of 18-FAB, and if so, your pairwise differences are just sign-reversed on the FAB scale.

Comment: thanks! I guess it's not that important, because it won't change the p-values and the general conclusions about the differences between the groups. Am I wrong?

Comment: I added an answer. I am concerned about that interaction with `visit_num` -- may not be advisable to average over that. Also, I really do like to see people show the EMMs, not just pairwise differences. Likely you did that here just to save space, but it's actually relevant to the question to see them.

Comment: Because you are saying the effect of `Group` depends on `visit_num`. Do `emmip(em, Group ~ visit_num)` to visualize, and realize that you are using the average of each curve.

Comment: Yes, I want to see if there are differences between the groups over time

Comment: Of course, but you have to do so using sensible methods. If the interaction doesn't matter to you, leave it out of the model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The detection of response transformations is pretty primitive, and it just gets interpreted as the square root, as illustrated with a similar example below:

```
> foo.lm = lm(sqrt(35 - mpg) ~ factor(cyl), data = mtcars)
> foo.emm = emmeans(foo.lm, "cyl")
> foo.emm
 cyl emmean    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
   4   2.76 0.171 29     2.41     3.11
   6   3.90 0.214 29     3.46     4.34
   8   4.45 0.152 29     4.14     4.76

Results are given on the sqrt (not the response) scale. 
Confidence level used: 0.95
```

So if you use `type = "response", you get estimates on the` 35 - mpg` scale:

```
> confint(foo.emm, type = "response")
 cyl response    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
   4      7.6 0.944 29     5.79     9.65
   6     15.2 1.674 29    12.00    18.84
   8     19.8 1.351 29    17.16    22.68

Confidence level used: 0.95 
Intervals are back-transformed from the sqrt scale
```

It *is* possible to translate this to the `mpg` scale using the `contrast` function with arguments `offset` and `scale`. We also add an `infer` argument to update the result so its default summary has confidence intervals.

```
> bar.emm = contrast(regrid(foo.emm), "identity", 
+     offset = 35, scale = -1, infer = c(TRUE, FALSE))
> bar.emm
 contrast estimate    SE df lower.CL upper.CL
 cyl4         27.4 0.944 29     25.5     29.3
 cyl6         19.8 1.674 29     16.3     23.2
 cyl8         15.2 1.351 29     12.4     17.9

Confidence level used: 0.95
```

Comment: Thank yon I follow your steps, but when I add to the contrast function, method="pairwise", it gives very weird estimates (very high). Please how can I get the pairwise comparisons and the p-values with the back-transformation?

Comment: Please try to understand the logic of what was done in my answer, which was to take the *estimates* (not the pairwise differences), multiply by -1, and add 35. If you use "pairwise" instead of "identity", you are doing that to each pairwise difference. If you want pairwise comparisons, do them with the results of the step I showed.

Comment: for maybe the ones that didn't understand the first time, the answer is `pairs(bar.emm, adjust="bonferroni")` . thanks @Russ